# How to use train_image_generator

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, keras

I am training a neural network. The network should be able to recognize characters on images, so I do not have separated image classes for my training and testing data. Therefore, I use Colab and to resize the images I would like to use the image_generator. Because Colab is relatively sensitive to big amounts of data, I would first like to only preprocess my training data. This training data is stored as a pickle file on my Google Drive under `/root/data/images.pkl`
I used the following code to load the data and preprocess the data.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

batch_size = 128
epochs = 15
IMG_HEIGHT = 224
IMG_WIDTH = 224

train_image_generator = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255) # Generator for our training data

train_data_gen = train_image_generator.flow_from_directory(batch_size=batch_size,
                                                           directory="/root/data/",
                                                           shuffle=True,
                                                           target_size=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH),
                                                           class_mode='categorical')
```

This returns:

```
Found 0 images belonging to 0 classes.
```

How can I fix this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you connected colab to google drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written in keras [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator), `flow_from_directory` search the given path for images with format PNG, JPG, BMP, PPM or TIF only. You need to un-pickle the images first.

Comment: That means, I should save the images directly as png files in my google Drive? If that is the case, I am unsure if Colab is able to process that many image files?

Comment: Yes you must save the images as ".png" files (or jpeg/tiff etc.). Colab has abilities to connect directly to google drive (I didn't tried it myself by see this the documentation 
 [link](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/io.ipynb#scrollTo=BaCkyg5CV5jF) ). By using a "generator" - you just load the relevant images in a batch when they are needed during training (meaning , you only load a batch of images at once, and not all of the images).